# Use operator in the select statement using case sql server2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, case

I create select statement for compare male and female and replace some values. I have two tables.

**Table 1:**

- Male (True or false)
- Female(True or false)

**Table 2:**

- Gender -values ('M','F','B')

I want to create select statement from Table 2 to Table 1. My query is follows,

```
select 'insert into table1(Male,female)values('+
   Isnull(cast(case  Gender when  'M' or 'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' end as varchar),'NULL')+','+
   Isnull(cast(case  Gender when 'F' or'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' End as varchar),'NUll')+')'
   from Table2
```

But I get error at or operator not using here. How to use operator to select both values. Anyone suggest me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
select 'insert into table1(Male,female)values('+
   Isnull(cast(case when Gender = 'M' or Gender = 'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' end as varchar),'NULL')+','+
   Isnull(cast(case when Gender = 'F' OR Gender = 'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' End as varchar),'NUll')+')'
   from Table2
```

or like this:

```
select 'insert into table1(Male,female)values('+
   Isnull(cast(case Gender when 'M' Then '''True''' when 'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' end as varchar),'NULL')+','+
   Isnull(cast(case Gender when 'F' Then '''True''' when 'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' End as varchar),'NUll')+')'
   from Table2
```

Answer (score 2):

For using dynamic SQL you need to declare a variable. Also it will help you with code testing

```
DECLARE @dml nvarchar(max) = N''
select @dml += 'insert into table1(Male,female)values('+
   Isnull(cast(case when Gender IN('M', 'B') 
                    Then '''True''' else '''false''' 
               end as varchar),'NULL')+','+
   Isnull(cast(case when Gender IN('F', 'B') 
                    Then '''True''' else '''false''' 
               end as varchar),'NUll')+')' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
from Table2
PRINT @dml
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'insert into table1(Male,female)values('+
   Isnull(cast(case  Gender when  'M' or Gender when 'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' end as varchar),'NULL')+','+
   Isnull(cast(case  Gender when 'F' or Gender when 'B' Then '''True''' else '''false''' End as varchar),'NUll')+')'
   from Table2
```

try this query.

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: i learnt "or" opearator is used only when we use "equal to" operator.